# Finding all elements in GF(2^4) in terms of given polynomial

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory

I'm working with polynomials over finite fields at the moment and a question.

I found this table http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~lomonaco/f97/442/Peterson_Table.html
and I picked a polynomial of degree 4 with 3 37D in the table. This gives the following polynomial:

$x^4 + x^3 + x^2 +x + 1$ which is $ξ^3$ which is NOT primitive.

So that polynomial p(x) is irreducible and has a degree of 4, which means that
$GF(2^4) = GF(2)[x] \,{\rm mod} \, p(x)$

I want to find all the elements of $GF(2^4)$ in terms of $ξ=x mod p(x)$

What's the best way to go about this? Does it matter that it's $ξ^3$ ?

Comment: What is $\xi^3$?

Comment: Check this link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XZwUF.png

So a way of representing the polynomial I think?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. What does it mean that `it's ξ³`? I've never met this expression.

Comment: Oh sorry, ξ is the primitive root. The above $ξ^3$ is not primitive.

Comment: Pfinferno, you are using conflicting notation. I cannot shake the feelling that this is a symptom of some confusion The coset $x+\langle p(x)\rangle$ is automatically a zero of the polynomial $p(x)$. In this case that is, as you seem to know, not a primitive element. So in this case a primitive element $\xi$ cannot be this coset. So let's denote $\alpha=x+\langle p(x)\rangle$. The elements of $GF(2^4)$ are then 
$b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2+b_3\alpha^3$, where $b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3\in\{0,1\}$. There are several primitive elements among them. For example $\xi=1+\alpha$.

Comment: Hmm, so it's the 16 different combinations of $b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2+b_3\alpha^3$ ? IE: 0, 1, α, 1+α, $α^2$, etc.? Where did that equation come from?

Comment: Also, why would $ξ^k$ not be a complete list of all the non-zero elements??

Comment: By polynomial division any coset of the ideal $I=\langle x^4+x^3+x^2+1\rangle$ in $GF(2)[x]$ has a unique representative of degree $<4$. Therefore listing all the polynomials of degree $\le3$ gives a list of the elements of $GF(16)$. The coset $\alpha=x+I$ is not primitive, because $$\alpha^5=1+(\alpha^5-1)=1+(\alpha-1)(\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1).$$ Because $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, or because $(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$ is an element of the ideal $I$, the latter term is zero in $GF(16)$. Therefore $\alpha^5=1$ and $\alpha$ is not primitive.

Comment: But are you at all familiar with the language of ideals and quotient rings of polynomial rings? I sense that your confusion comes from that source. For example, is it clear to you that a primitive element $\xi=x+\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$ is different from the non-primitive element $\alpha=x+\langle x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\rangle$?